# Game of Life ArrayIndexOutofBounds

Tags: java, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array

I'm doing the Conway's game of life.  I'm pretty sure I'm close to finished, but when I run it, I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at game.of.life.GameOfLife.generation(GameOfLife.java:77)
    at game.of.life.GameOfLife.main(GameOfLife.java:32)
Java Result: 1`

I'm assuming when the method that checks neighbors at the edges of the array, there's nothing there so it dies or something.  I just don't know how to make it so that doesn't happen.  Does anyone have any thoughts?  Code below.

```
package game.of.life;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GameOfLife {
static boolean[][] current = new boolean[10][10];
static boolean[][] old = new boolean[10][10];
static int population = 10;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = " @ ";
    String b = " ' ";
    int choice = 9;
    int gencount = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Choose population density. i.e. 10 = 10%: ");
    population = input.nextInt();
    populate();
    copy();
    for(int r = 0; r < current.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < current[r].length; c++){
            if(current[r][c] == true){
                System.out.print(a);
            }
            else
                System.out.print(b);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print("Generation " + gencount + ".");
    while(choice != 0){
        System.out.print("Make a selection: 1 - Advance Generation 0 - Exit");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if(choice == 1){
            generation();
            for(int r = 0; r < current.length; r++){
                for(int c = 0; c < current[r].length; c++){
                    if(current[r][c] == true){
                        System.out.print(a);
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.print(b);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            copy();
            gencount += 1;
            System.out.println("Generation" + gencount + ".");
        }
    }
}
private static void generation(){
    for(int r = 0; r < old.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < old[r].length; c++){
            if (old[r][c] == true){
                int neighbors = 0;
                if(old[r + 1][c] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r - 1][c] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r][c + 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r][c - 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r + 1][c + 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r + 1][c - 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r - 1][c - 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r - 1][c + 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(neighbors != 3 || neighbors != 2)
                    current[r][c] = false;
            }
            else if(old[r][c] == false){
                int neighbors = 0;
                if(old[r + 1][c] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r - 1][c] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r][c + 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r][c - 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r + 1][c + 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r + 1][c - 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r - 1][c - 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(old[r - 1][c + 1] == true)
                    neighbors += 1;
                if(neighbors == 3)
                    current[r][c] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
private static void populate(){
    for(int r = 0; r < current.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < current[r].length; c++){
            int q = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            if(q < population){
                current[r][c] = true;
            }
            else{
                current[r][c] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
private static void copy(){
    for(int r = 0; r < old.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < old[r].length; c++)
            old[r][c] = current[r][c];
    }
}
}
```

If anyone can help me out it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you tell us where line 77 is...

Comment: oh sorry, 32 is the generation method call, and line 77 is `if(old[r - 1][c] == true)`.  How can I get it to ignore if it checks and there isn't anything there.

Answer (score 3):

When `r` is `0`, this one is not valid: `old[r - 1][c]`.
Thus you get the exception you posted.

I suggest you simplify it like this.

```
    boolean isValidPosition(int r, int c){
        return 
            0 <= r && r < N &&
            0 <= c && c < M;

    }

    int getNeighboursCount(boolean[][] old, int r, int c){
        int neighbors = 0;
        for (int i=-1; i<=1; i++){
            for (int j=-1; j<=1; j++){
                if (i!=0 || j!=0){
                    if (isValidPosition(r + i, c + j)){
                        if(old[r + i][c + j])
                        {
                            neighbors++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return neighbors;
    }
```

Comment: right, that likely applies to all of the edges.  Is there a way to get it to ignore it if there's nothing there?

Comment: Yes, write a method isValidPosition and a method getNeighboursCount.

Comment: Also, if b is boolean, don't check if (b==true) but do if (b). Your code is probably logically OK but is not really in good style. It can be cleaned up and simplified a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you basically have two choices:

1. apply finite bounds, that is, for the cells in the first and last columns and rows, you implement an additional check when counting the number of 'living' neighbours.
2. apply periodic bounds, that is, the cells on the leftmost column and the cells on the rightmost column are considered as neighbours. With the help of modular arithmetic, these cells don't need to be handled separately from others.

Comment: number 2 sounds like the better fix, but I don't know how to do that.  Do you know of any documentation I could look at?

Comment: I don't know any documentation, but basically whenever you are indexing for a neighbouring cell, for example `old[r+1][c-1]`, you should apply a modular division like `old[(r+1)%totalNumberOfRows][(c-1+totalNumberOfColumns)%totalNumberOfColumns]`. Be aware, that `%` operator behaves differently for negative numbers as for positive ones, that's why an additional addition has to be applied in that case - as in the example I just showed. In your code, both `totalNumberOfColumns` and `totalNumberOfRows` is 10, if I'm not wrong.