# Java: How to implement edge checking in Game of Life

Tags: java, algorithm

I am having trouble implementing an edge check algorithm into my code. I have the meat of the code written. Without checking for errors, it always throws me an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error.

```
public class CreateLife {
private int dimension;
private boolean[][] world;
private long generation;
Life(int dimension){
    this.dimension = dimension;
    createBoard();
    this.generation = 0;
}


// Randomly decides which cells are alive or dead in starting generation.
private void createBoard(){
    boolean[][] board = new boolean[dimension][dimension];
    for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++ ){
        for(int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++ ){
            board[row][col] = (Math.random() < 0.3);
        }
    }
    world = board;
}

// Makes the intial gameboard array.
public void makeWorld(){
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Generation:" + generation);
    for(int row = 0; row < world.length; row++ ){
        for(int col = 0; col < world[row].length; col++ ){
             System.out.print(world[row][col] ? '*' : ' ');
             System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// Second array/ gameboard to store next generation 
public void nextGeneration(int genCheck){
    boolean[][] newWorld = new boolean[dimension][dimension];
    for(int row = 0; row < newWorld.length; row++ ){
        for(int col = 0; col < newWorld[row].length; col++ ){
            newWorld[row][col] = isAlive(row, col);
        }
    }
    world = newWorld;
    generation++;

    //Exits program if user input generation is met
    if (generation == genCheck + 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing the Game Of Life");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

// THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING ISSUES 

private boolean isAlive(int r, int c){
    int count = 0;
    boolean checkEdge;
    boolean cellCurrentlyAlive = world[r][c];

    if (world [r - 1][ c -1] = true) {
        count++;
    }
    if (world [r - 1][ c  ] = true) {
        count++;
    }
    if (world [r - 1][ c + 1] = true) {
        count++;
    }
    if (world [r][ c - 1] = true) {
        count++;
    }
    if (world [r ][ c + 1] = true) {
        count++;
    }
    if (world [r + 1][ c - 1] = true) {
        count++;
    }   
    if (world [r + 1][ c] = true) {
        count++;
    }
    if (world [r + 1][ c + 1] = true) {
        count++;
    }



    if(cellCurrentlyAlive){
        count--;
    }

    // The game of life rules coded
    if(count == 2 && cellCurrentlyAlive){
        return true;
    } else if(count == 3){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I do have an idea on how to look for the edge using these if statements

```
 public class LifeUtils
 {
 public static boolean isEdge(char[][] w, int r, int c)
 {
 //it it in an edge ?
 if((r == 0) || (r == w.length-1) || (c == 0) || (c == w.length-1))
    return true;
 else
    return false;
 }

 public static boolean isTopEdge(int r, int c)
 {
    if(r == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
 }

 public static boolean isBottomEdge(int r, char[][] w)
 {
    if(r == w.length-1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
 }

 public static boolean isLeftEdge(int c)
 {
    if(c == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public static boolean isRightEdge(int c, char[][] w)
 {
  if(c == w.length-1)
    return true;
 else
    return false;
}
}
```

Could anyone help me get started with an algorithm? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What went wrong when you tried this?

Comment: Where is the error at?  What does the error say?  It should give you a line number

Comment: Also note that in `LifeUtil`, most of the functions are `if(bool) return true; else return false;`, which can be simplified to `return bool;`

Comment: Sometimes you are calling `isAlive(r,c)` with `r` and/or `c` having a value of `0` . In that case, `world [r - 1][ c -1]` will give you the above error , there is no `-1` index.

Comment: What behavior do you want to implement at the edges? Identify left edge with right edge, top edge with bottom edge? (like in a torus)

Comment: Also note that in `isAlive`, you use `if(world[r - 1][ c -1] = true)`, which will always be true.  You may have meant to use `==` instead of `=`, or better yet just remove `= true` (`bool == true` is the same as `bool`)

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at line 41 and 62

Comment: @BryanLee What's the full error message?  I'm guessing it's at the line with `if (world [r - 1][ c -1] = true)`.  You're checking `r-1` and `c-1` when `r` and `c` are both 0.  You should check if the destination is in bounds before using it

Comment: @Bryan Lee: Line numbers are not really useful here, because the code you posted has no line numbers.

Comment: The simples way to handle boundaries is going with the second idea of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22584911/1921273